# Insert or update using a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update values using a dictionary.
My `user_id` is set. I want to `update date_synced where user_id=user_id`. User table looks like this: `User(user_id, mail, active, activity_level, date_synced)`.

Dictionary dictUsers looks like:

```
[{'user_id': 1, 'date_synced': '2019-05-22 10:42:25'},
 {'user_id': 8, 'date_synced': '2019-05-22 10:42:25'}]
```

What I've tried:

```
sql = 'UPDATE User SET {}'.format(', '.join('{}'.format(k) for k in dictUsers))
conn.execute(sql, dictUsers.values())
```

My error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Expected output is date_synced updated in my User table. How can I do this?

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with `mysql`.
2. Print out `sql` to see if it is what you expected
3. dictUsers is a `list`, `list` do not have `values` method.

Comment: generating SQL like this is almost guaranteed to have SQL injection attacks, look at using [parameterised queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902417/1358308)

Comment: @ch33hau 'UPDATE User SET {'user_id': 1, 'date_synced': '2019-05-22 10:42:25'}, {'user_id': 8, 'date_synced': '2019-05-22 10:42:25'}' This is what I get.

Comment: @SamMason A problem for when the query works

Comment: yea I know, and this is an invalid sql, you might want to fix your `sql` string before fixing the next line.

Comment: I'd suggest figuring out what an `UPDATE` statement looks like my crafting it by hand first, looking up the docs as needed, then write code to replicate it as much as needed

Comment: @ch33hau Problem is I can't find a lot about updating with a dictionary. I know what a normal update statement looks like with multiple values, but I can't recreate it with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (from the [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#multiple-table-updates)):

```
stmt = users.update().\
        values(name='ed wood').\
        where(users.c.id == addresses.c.id)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

In your case this should be something like this. You can loop this over your dictionary to do for every user:

```
stmt = user.update().\
        values(date_synced=dictUsers[i].date_synced).\
        where(user.c.user_id == dictUsers[i].user_id)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: When I loop over with 'for key, value in dictUsers.items():' I still get the same error. List object has no attribute items.